# How to show process tree with specified attributes

Tags: command-line, pstree

The command `pstree` shows a process tree such as this

```
systemd-+--agetty
        +--dbus-daemon
        +--login----bash---pstree
        +--systemd-qqsd
```

I want to show a process tree with some specified attribute for each process (may be `stat` or `pid`... - options that you can specify with `ps -o`)

Is there a way to achieve this behavior with `pstree` or any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `top`? Start top then hit <kbd>V</kbd> (capital V) to display process tree.

Press <kbd>f</kbd>  to select the fields to display.

Answer (score 0):

`pstree` and specific attributes are also part of `bashtop`. The attributes could be switched by shortcuts. In ubuntu it can be installed by

`sudo apt install bashtop`

[image]